# Confusion With Index Notation in Field Theory

Tags: electromagnetism, metric-tensor, field-theory, tensor-calculus, notation

I'm working through Quantum Field Theory and the Standard Model by Matthew Schwartz, and am having trouble with part of chapter 3.4. Specifically some of the tensor manipulation is bothering me.
While deriving Coulomb's Law from classical filed theory the following expression comes up:

$$\frac{\partial(\partial_{\beta}A_{\gamma})}{\partial(\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu})}g_{\beta\gamma}~=~g_{\beta\mu}g_{\gamma\nu}g_{\beta\gamma},\tag{3.44}$$
Where $g_{\mu\nu}$ is the Minkowski metric. My problem is that writing out $\partial_{\beta}A_{\gamma}$, as a matrix and differentiating with respect to a single element $\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu}$, seems to give:

$$\frac{\partial(\partial_{\beta}A_{\gamma})}{\partial(\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu})}g_{\beta\gamma}~=~\delta^{\beta}_{\mu}\delta^{\gamma}_{\nu}g_{\beta\gamma}~=~g_{\mu\nu}.\tag{3.44'}$$

I think part of my confusion could be related to raised vs lowered indices. Schwartz states that they really don't matter in QFT, but ignoring them honestly seems more confusing than paying attention to them is tedious.

Comment: It definitely matters because sometimes g means g and sometimes it means g inverse! You can hide the indices and get away with it but you have to remember what kind of tensor everything is as you go along. If you read math literature in Riemannian geometry there are very few indices but a lot of talking about what bundle everything is a section of.

Comment: Yeah definitely, but in Minkowski space at least, g is its own inverse right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How come $\frac{\partial(\partial_{\beta}A_{\gamma})}{\partial(\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu})} = g_{\beta\mu}g_{\gamma\nu}$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/355018/)

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't seen that, I'll close this now. Thanks for pointing it out, I really appreciate the help.

Comment: I think it's still not good to identify g with its inverse, even if they look the same in some special coordinate system.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, if we insist on covariant index positions, then eq. (3.44) should read
$$\frac{\partial(\partial_{\beta}A_{\gamma})}{\partial(\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu})}g^{\beta\gamma}~=~\delta_{\beta}^{\mu}\delta_{\gamma}^{\nu}g^{\beta\gamma}~=~g^{\mu\nu}.\tag{3.44''}$$

Comment: I agree fully with this and really appreciate your help, but I still don't understand why Schwartz uses the metric tensor in place of the kronecker delta.