# Four-vector differentiation (E-M Euler-Lagrange eq.)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, field-theory, differentiation, variational-calculus

$$\partial_{\mu} \frac{\partial(\partial_{\alpha}A_{\alpha})^2}{\partial(\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu})} = \partial_{\mu}\left[2(\partial_{\alpha}A_{\alpha})\frac{\partial(\partial_{\beta}A_{\gamma})}{\partial(\partial_{\mu}A_{\nu})} g_{\beta\gamma}\right]$$

I assume the metric comes from differentiating a vector wrt to another and chain rule is applied, but I can't see how exactly these two sides are equal.

Comment: from Schwartz QFT book (3.43), here it is been discussed further (but not the first step) https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/355018/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the OP's [link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/355018/how-come-frac-partial-partial-betaa-gamma-partial-partial-mua) Schwartz (in his QFT book) doesn't keep track of the index placement on tensor objects that might obscure the structure a little.

However, ignoring the first derivative $\partial_\mu$ (because it is not relevant for the answer) the starting point is to distinguish between covariant and contravariant indices such that
$$ (\partial_\alpha A_\alpha)^2 \to (\partial_\alpha A^\alpha)^2=(\partial_\alpha A^\alpha)(\partial_\beta A^\beta)\ .$$

Applying the product rule we see
$$\frac{\partial (\partial_\alpha A^\alpha)(\partial_\beta A^\beta)}{\partial (\partial_\mu A_\nu)}= \frac{\partial (\partial_\alpha A^\alpha)}{\partial (\partial_\mu A_\nu)}(\partial_\beta A^\beta)+(\partial_\alpha A^\alpha)\frac{\partial(\partial_\beta A^\beta)}{\partial (\partial_\mu A_\nu)}\ .$$

Since the indices must be at the right position in order to perform a derivative we can use the metric to write $\partial_\alpha A^\alpha= g^{\alpha\gamma}\partial_\alpha A_\gamma$ similar for the second expression.

Hence, the Euler-Lagrange variation involves a metric
$$\frac{\partial (\partial_\alpha A^\alpha)}{\partial (\partial_\mu A_\nu)}=\frac{\partial (\partial_\alpha A_\gamma)}{\partial (\partial_\mu A_\nu)}g^{\alpha\gamma}\ .$$

Collecting all pieces and replacing the labeling of dummy indices $\alpha \leftrightarrow \beta$ this leads eventually to the result in the brackets
$$\frac{\partial (\partial_\alpha A^\alpha)(\partial_\beta A^\beta)}{\partial (\partial_\mu A_\nu)} = (\partial_\beta A^\beta)\frac{\partial (\partial_\alpha A_\gamma)}{\partial (\partial_\mu A_\nu)}g^{\alpha\gamma}+(\partial_\alpha A^\alpha)\frac{\partial(\partial_\beta A_\gamma)}{\partial (\partial_\mu A_\nu)}g^{\beta \gamma}\\
=(\partial_\alpha A^\alpha)\frac{\partial (\partial_\beta A_\gamma)}{\partial (\partial_\mu A_\nu)}g^{\beta\gamma}+(\partial_\alpha A^\alpha)\frac{\partial(\partial_\beta A_\gamma)}{\partial (\partial_\mu A_\nu)}g^{\beta \gamma}\\
=2 (\partial_\alpha A^\alpha)\frac{\partial (\partial_\beta A_\gamma)}{\partial (\partial_\mu A_\nu)}g^{\beta\gamma}\ .$$